# Join lines between a string - bash

Tags: linux, bash, join, merge

I have a nmap output file that contains data similar to -

```
Nmap scan report for myserver1 (11.11.11.11)

OS CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2003::sp2

OS details: Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP2

Nmap scan report for myserver2 (22.22.22.22)

OS CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2003::sp2

OS details: Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP2

Nmap scan report for 33.33.33.33

OS CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_xp::sp3

Aggressive OS guesses: Microsoft Windows XP SP3 (98%), Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP2 (96%), Microsoft Windows XP (94%), Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP0 or Windows XP SP2 (94%), Microsoft Windows XP SP2 (94%), Microsoft Windows XP SP2 - SP3 (94%), Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP1 or SP2 (92%), Microsoft Windows XP SP2 or SP3 (91%), Microsoft Windows Server 2003 (91%), Belkin OmniView KVM switch or SMA Sunny WebBox solar panel monitor (90%)

No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).

....etc
```

I want to join all the lines specific to each server into one line, starting with "Nmap scan report". The number of lines for each server can be variable so I can't use grep -A. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I have a code, but I'd love to know first what you use it for :)

Comment: Are there really those blank lines?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
tr "\n" " " < filename | sed -r "s/ (Nmap scan report for)/\n\1/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
sed -re 's/^(Nmap)/@@@\1/g' file | tr -d '\n'| sed -re 's/@@@/\n/g'
```

Explanation:

1. Insert `@@@` at the beginning of the line where the line starts
   with `Nmap`
2. Deletes `\n` with `tr`
3. Replace `@@@` by `\n`

Another way with `grep`:

`tr  '\n' ' ' < file | grep -Po 'Nmap.*?(?=Nmap|$)'`

Or even better with `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; s/^(Nmap)/\n$1/g; print "$_ " ' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    NR>1 && /^Nmap scan report/ {print ""} 
    {printf "%s ", $0} 
    END {print ""}
' filename
```

or, use the specified string as the *record separator*, and remove newlines from each record:

```
awk -v RS="Nmap scan report" 'NR>1 {gsub(/\n/, " "); print RS $0}' filename
```